# Why RichTextBox replaces <CR> characters?

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I've noticed that RichTextBox replaces CR with LF or empty string. 
VB example:

```
Dim s1 As String = vbCr
RichTextBox1.Text = s1
Dim s2 String = RichTextBox1.Text

s1 = s2 => False
s1 => <CR>
s2 => <LF>
```

Or

```
Dim s1 As String = vbCrLf
RichTextBox1.Text = s1
Dim s2 String = RichTextBox1.Text

s1 = s2 => False
s1 => <CR><LF>
s2 => <LF>
```

Why it behaves like that and is there way to change it, to force it to store those  characters properly (and if it does any other changes to input text to prevent it too)?

I'm creating messages for communication with another application and it is important not to change any of the characters because messages will be rejected.

Comment: It is just the way the animal works, line-endings are vbLf, not vbCrLf as they normally are in the rest of Windows.  How this came about is lost in the fog of history.  You'll have to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Rtf property of RichTextBox control. However if you need to have full control over what gets submitted, RichTextBox is not the best option. It is storing the entered text in its own internal data structures and acts more like a black box. What are your business requirements anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Since RTF is a markup language (like HTML) line endings have virtually no meaning. RTF uses `\par` to start a new paragraph.

From the [specs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140283%28v=office.10%29.aspx#rtfspec_specialchar):

> A carriage return (character value 13) or linefeed (character value
>   10) will be treated as a \par control if the character is preceded by
>   a backslash. You must include the backslash; otherwise, RTF ignores
>   the control word. (You may also want to insert a
>   carriage-return/linefeed pair without backslashes at least every 255
>   characters for better text transmission over communication lines.)

Since there are multiple characters that will be replaced by `\par` you can never get back the original character.

Hence the RichTextBox control is the wrong choice here. If you can provide more information on your goal somebody can probably suggest a better approach.